# Rails_admin undefined method `associations' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have these models:

```
Class A 
   embeds_many :b
end

Class B
   belongs_to :c
end

Class C
end
```

I'm working with [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) and mongoid. In admin, when I try to retrieve the list of C records when I'm creating an A instance I'm getting this error:

This only happens on production envirnment not in development

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `associations' for nil:NilClass):
      /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@mh-backend/bundler/gems/rails_admin-355dc80f8a20/lib/rails_admin/adapters/mongoid/abstract_object.rb:10:in `initialize'
      /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@mh-backend/bundler/gems/rails_admin-355dc80f8a20/lib/rails_admin/adapters/mongoid.rb:24:in `new'
      /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@mh-backend/bundler/gems/rails_admin-355dc80f8a20/lib/rails_admin/adapters/mongoid.rb:24:in `get'
      /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@mh-backend/bundler/gems/rails_admin-355dc80f8a20/app/controllers/rails_admin/main_controller.rb:138:in `get_association_scope_from_params'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at rails_admin code we can see that piece of code in **mongoid.rb** file.

```
    def get(id)
        AbstractObject.new(model.find(id))
      rescue => e
        raise e if %w(
          Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound
          Mongoid::Errors::InvalidFind
          Moped::Errors::InvalidObjectId
          BSON::InvalidObjectId
        ).exclude?(e.class.to_s)
      end
```

If we pay attention at this code we can see that model.find(id) must produce a Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound if document doesn't exists by default.

However, in mongoid you can avoid the raise of this error with **raise_not_found_error: true** in mongo config file, this produce the undefined method of nil class.

[Tracking issue on github](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2623)

Comment: a thousand thanks! I've been struggling with this errors for hours and it seemed no one has experienced it before.

Comment: Adding `raise_not_found_error: true` here only raises a more helpful exception, but doesn't fix the problem, which is that an exception is raised when selecting an associated model for a new (unpersisted) record.  That is a bug, which was already tracked here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2114